# How to append every third line in Vim?

Tags: vim, append

I'm not at all familiar with Vim but I'm working with large text files (~1G) and my standard text editors weren't cutting it.

My files are currently in this format:

```
Arbitrary_title_of_sequenceA
SEQ1SEQ1SEQ1SEQ1
SEQ2SEQ2SEQ2SEQ2
Arbitrary_title_of_sequenceB
SEQ1SEQ1SEQ1SEQ1
SEQ2SEQ2SEQ2SEQ2
```

I need a convenient way of appending the "SEQ2" line to the "SEQ1" line like so:

```
Arbitrary_title_of_sequenceA
SEQ1SEQ1SEQ1SEQ1SEQ2SEQ2SEQ2SEQ2
Arbitrary_title_of_sequenceB
SEQ1SEQ1SEQ1SEQ1SEQ2SEQ2SEQ2SEQ2
```

Considering the size of these files, doing each line separately isn't really an option. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

What about providing a correct sample to begin with?

```
:g/SEQ1/norm Jx
```

does what *I think* you want.

- `:g/SEQ1` is the `:global` command which allows you to act on each line containing the pattern `SEQ1`. See `:help :global`.
- `norm` is the `:normal` command that you use to perform a normal mode command, here on every line matched by `:g/SEQ1`. See `:help :normal`.

After that comes the normal command in question:

- `J` is used to join the current line with the line below.
- `x` is used to remove the `<Space>` automatically added by Vim.

Comment: Vim golf time: `:g/SEQ1/j!`. `:j` is short for `:join` which is the ex command for joining lines. The `!` means `:join` will not insert or delete any spaces. see `:h :j` for more help

Comment: Depending on which of the three kinds of lines are easier to match with a pattern, besides `:g/SEQ1/j!` also consider `:g/SEQ2/-j!` and `:g/title/+j!`.  Note that these three commands are the most efficient compared to substitutions or Normal mode commands.

Comment: You guys rock. My initial answer was actually based on matching `SEQ2` but I thought it was more efficient to match `SEQ1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
:1,$s/\(.*\n\)\(.*\)\n\(.*\n\)/\1\2\3/

1,$          -> range is all file
s/PAT1/PAT2/ -> substitute PAT1 with PAT2
.*           -> match any character except new line
\n           -> match new line
\(PAT1\)     -> capture/remember the string that matched PAT1
\1,\2,\3     -> refers to the captured string for captures in order
```

Also using sed instead of vim should be faster:

```
sed -i 'n;N;s/\n/ /' input_file
```

This can be summarized as:

```
Read a line
Read another line and print previous line (n)
Read another line and append it to the previous line (N)
find the first newline and change it to space (s/\n/ /)
print the line (or merged lines)
```

Comment: Should't the sed command be: `sed -i 'n;N;s/\n//' input_file`. Note the `s/\n//`, so to not leave a space between the freshly joined lines.

Answer (score 1):

I think romainl's solution is the best *if* you have a reliable "SEQ1" pattern you can grab onto. If not and you want to literally join every third line, you could easily do this with a macro:

```
qqjJxjq
```

Hit `G` to see how many lines are in the file and just repeat the macro that many times (it doesn't matter that it's higher than you need). So if the file was 1000 lines you could do `1000@q`. This kind of solution is easy to remember and integrate into your normal workflow.